# Azure Devops AgentPools to perform this action: Administer Permissions

Tags: devops, azure-devops-server, pipeline

I Have Azure DevOps on-prem Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1

I have a project collection administrator privilege.

when I try to create a new agent pool or add an agent to the current agent pool I get error that says

"
Access denied. Ahmed A. Sobeeh needs Manage permissions to perform the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps Server administrator."

if i tried to add myself as admin on the agent pool security git the below error

Access Denied: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;S-1-5-21-2315945116-4195333612-642830686-21480 needs the following permission(s) on the resource AgentPools to perform this action: Administer Permissions

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7hrV.png)